# Java variable that only accept a specific range of values

Tags: java, instance-variables, instance-methods

I'm new to this so please bear with me. I have homework and I don't really understand what exactly the teacher means by this.

> **The class name is Elevator**
>
> level stores the current level.
> level is an instance-variable of type int
>
> Limit the number of levels from -2 to 10.
>
> Then create a method called goTo(Level: int).(will send messages)

By limiting to a specific range I guess he means by using a if-statement? If I'm right do I add it in the method below because I can't create if statements directly in the class.

And also why is the method where(): int supposed to return level. It is never used...

```
public class Elevator {

    int level = 0;

    public void goTo(int level){

        if (level < this.level){
            System.out.println("Elevator going up to floor " + level);
        }
        else if (level > this.level){
            System.out.println("Elevator going  down to floor " + level);
        }
        else if (level == this.level){
            System.out.println("Elevator already on the floor " + level);
        }

    }

    public int where(){
        return level;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you should add if statement in method `goTo()` and `where()` is just used to teach you about getters. Don't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my point of view that limit should be an if statement in goTo method to prevent sending level different than -2 to 10. So it should looks e.g like that:

```
public class Elevator {

    int actualLevel = 0;

    public void goTo(int level) {
        if (level < -2 || level > 10) {
            System.out.println("Invalid level!. Levels range is -2 to 10.");
            return;
        }

        if (level > actualLevel) {
            System.out.println("Elevator going up to floor " + level);
            this.actualLevel = level;
        } else if (level < actualLevel) {
            System.out.println("Elevator going  down to floor " + level);
            this.actualLevel = level;
        } else if (level == actualLevel) {
            System.out.println("Elevator already on the floor " + level);
        }
    }

    public int where() {
        return this.actualLevel;
    }

}
```

Also I made changes in your class variable name because there was mistake in checking if elevetator goes up or down because you mistake method and class variables. And one more thing that if the elevator goes up or down you should assign it to your class variable to hold actual floor.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an addendum:

> Limit the number of levels from -2 to 10.

The *real* problem here isn't that you need a sequence of if/else statements. It is actually the (left out) detail: how to react to wrong input. In your case, you are probably fine with: the `goTo()` method doing **nothing** when a wrong number is provided.

Whereas, in a more complex situation, it might be more appropriate to *somehow* tell the caller of that method: your input to me isn't valid. For example by throwing some sort exception.

Coming back to that simple case, what is missing from your code is this: when the user picks a **valid** new level, you want that assignment to happen:

```
if(newLevel < - 2 || newLevel > 10 ) {
... // checks for valid input
if (newLevel < newLevel) {
... // the required print statements

// finally, make the elevator actually go to the new level
level = newLevel;
```

(and yes: prefer to name that parameter **differently** than the class field. the parameter is actually that: the intended new level to move to. a distinct name helps avoiding mistakes)

Answer (score 0):

First you have a small mixup between local `level` and the Elevator's level.

Now min and max level are properties of the elevator. You can store them as a (constant) field too.
Below I use them direct in the code. Which is not no easy to grasp, that the house has onely those floors.

```
public class Elevator {

    int cabinLevel = 0;

    public void goTo(int level) {
        if (level < -2) {
            return;
        }
        if (level Y > 12) {
            return;
        }

        if (level < this.cabinLevel){
            System.out.println("Elevator going D O W N to floor " + level);
            cabinLevel = level;
        } else if (...) {
```